# Supabase REST: how to refresh token?

Tags: api, rest, supabase

I'm using the supabase api (REST) with SWR. I have almost all endpoints to `login`, `logout`, `invite`, `update` an user, etc, but I can't find the endpoint to refresh the token.

Anyone knows about this endpoint?

I tried:

- `/auth/v1/refresh`
- `/auth/v1/refreshToken`
- `/auth/v1/refresh/token`
- `/auth/v1/token/refresh`

Without result (404)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combining [this](https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js/blob/86fe3511ce5f6d4c7ccf85db8e9a824e4db60fb6/src/SupabaseClient.ts#L93) base URL and [this](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue-js/blob/5c43ca5ffda8b9cccc493a47a4d3a6194a057ad2/src/GoTrueClient.ts#L840) path is the endpoint that Supabase is calling to refresh the token, so it would be

`/auth/v1/token?grant_type=refresh_token`

You should be able to take a look at what other parameters are required to call this endpoint by looking at the code inside [here](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue-js/blob/5c43ca5ffda8b9cccc493a47a4d3a6194a057ad2/src/GoTrueClient.ts#L838)!

Comment: method is POST and body `{ refresh_token: "the-refresh-token" }`

Answer (score 3):

METHOD:

```
POST
```

URL:

```
https://*subdomain_example*.supabase.co/auth/v1/token?grant_type=refresh_token
```

HEADERS:

```
apikey : *xxxxxxxxxexamlexxxxxxxxxx*
```

BODY:

```
 { "refresh_token" : "*wXExampleXlxIxMxkzDIQ2YwgF_VhXw*" }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).